# Legend grafana not working after updating to version 10

Tags: grafana-loki

I'm currently using the "grafana/grafana:9.3.13" image, I wanted to update my version of grafana to version 10 but since then the captions on my graphs no longer work. Before, my caption syntax was as follows:

```
Remote address {{remote_addr}}"
```

But since version 10, it no longer works.

You can see here, it is completely different depending on version :
[difference between the rendering of version 9.3.13 and version 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8PMR.png)

Here is an image of my syntax: [loki legend syntax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PL8sn.png)

Does someone know what changed between these versions ? And how to write the legends correctly now ?

Comment: It seems like legend option was simply ignored: if it had troubles parsing your syntax it would simply replace everything with unparsed value, and you'd see `status: {{status}}` in every line. Try changing legend in some way, maybe this will trigger update, and legend will be re-rendered.

Comment: Version 10 still supports legends in the same way. You can see it at [this demo](https://play.grafana.org/d/T512JVH7z/loki-nginx-service-mesh-json-version?orgId=1&from=1693191749264&to=1693213349264&viewPanel=2)